# First order ODE definition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is a first order differential equation categorized by $f(y',y,x) = 0$ or $y'=f(y,x) $?

In the case of the second, why $\sin y' + 3y + x +5 = 0$  isnt a first order differential equation ?

Answer (score 1):

The first criterion is the same:
$$
y' = f(y,x) \Rightarrow g(y,y',x) \equiv y' - f(y,x) = 0
$$
If you expand a sine in a Taylor power series, you get arbitrary high powers of y'.

Comment: omg, so actually siny' + 3y + x +5 = 0 has infinity order ?

Comment: What order is  siny' + 3y + x +5 = 0  ? If you follow most of the books it says it is order 1 because the order is dictated by the highest derivative of y.

Answer (score 1):

Both are first order. The second is linear but first may not be necessarily linear.

Answer (score 1):

Now i understand, any function in the form of f(y',y,x) = 0 can be solved for y' and writen in y'=f(y,x) .

In the case i mentioned, in the form of f(y',y,x) = 0 we would have why siny' + 3y + x +5 = 0   and in the form of y'=f(y,x) we would have y' = arcsin(-3y-x-5).

Comment: That seems correct to me!